# Open new tab in ITerm2 and run commands there with zsh script

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I want make a shell script to startup my project env. 
I'm using ITerm2 with zsh and oh-my-zsh installed.

I want to:

1. Open directory
2. Activate python virtualenv
3. Run django manage command
4. Switch to the new tab
5. change directory
6. Run gulp command to watch for frontend changes

All I got is this:

```
#!/bin/zsh
cd ~/Projects/python/project_name
source ~/virtualenvs/project_name/bin/activate
python ./backend/manage.py runserver 
tab
cd front
gulp watch
```

And as you can expect this doesn't work. Can you point me direction where I should look or is this even possible to do with just shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely possible.

I did pretty much the same thing you're trying (although it is a Rails project) using an NPM package called ttab.

1. [Install NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).
2. [Install TTab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttab).
3. You can run the commands in the new tab like so:

```bash
# First switch to directory
cd front
# Open new tab in that directory and execute
ttab -G eval "gulp watch"
```

*Note:* You can execute several commands if needed, like `gulp watch; rails s`.

4. If you need to run a command on the original tab that is also on a different directory, you can create a procedure/function in your script file to do that:

```bash
# Define the function before it is called
gotofolder()
{
  cd ~/mydirectory
}

# start the other tabs (...)

# change the original tab directory
gotofolder
# Run Rails or whatever
./bin/rails s
```

If you want to take a look at how I did this, please checkout the `confereai.sh` script in [my MDFR repo](https://github.com/jaysoifer/MDFR).

Comment: Hi! I found this package too, but I didnt know about functions. Thanks

Comment: I'm seing your answer now @jaysoifer but the link to MDFR is not working, if you please update it would be super helpful.

Comment: @ŁukaszStaniszewski Bash's functions are explained [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html)